# Sum two variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hi m trying to get the total price of multiple items as total price but it shows the total price of single single product, the pic is:  https://ibb.co/YkZgfXV

here is code of cart.blade.php:

```
   <table>
   <tr class="table-row">
                        <?php $total_amount = 0; ?>
                        @foreach($userCart as $cart)
                        <td class="column-1">
                            <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
                                <img src="{{ asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$cart->image) }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td class="column-2">{{ $cart->product_name }}</td>
                        <td class="column-3">PKR: {{ $cart->price }}</td>
                        <td class="column-4">
                            <div class="flex-w bo5 of-hidden w-size17">
                                <a class="cart_quantity_up color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2" href="{{ url('/cart/update-quantity/'.$cart->id.'/1') }}">+</a>
                                <input class="size8 m-text18 t-center num-product" type="number" name="quantity" value="{{ $cart->quantity }}">
                                @if($cart->quantity>1)
                                <a class="cart_quantity_down color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2" href="{{ url('/cart/update-quantity/'.$cart->id.'/-1') }}">-</a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="column-5">PKR: {{ $cart->price }}</td>
                        <td class="column-6"><a href="{{ url('/cart/delete-product/'.$cart->id)}}">X</a></td>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                </table>

        <!-- Total -->
            <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-26 p-b-30">
                @foreach($userCart as $cart)
                <span class="m-text22 w-size19 w-full-sm">
                    Total:
                </span>

                <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
                    PKR: {{ $cart->price*$cart->quantity }}
                </span>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Comment: Why not calculate with controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute the total of the cart before displaying it. Something like this:

```
<div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-26 p-b-30">
    @php 
        $total = 0; 
        foreach($userCart as $cart) {
            $total += ($cart->price * $cart->quantity); 
        }
    @endphp
    <span class="m-text22 w-size19 w-full-sm">
        Total:
    </span>
    <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
        PKR: {{ $total }}
    </span>
</div>
```

You can keep the html above in your blade as it is. Also, views shouldn't have that kind of logic in it. It should be, for example, in a controller.

Comment: its showing total price according to the products, mean if  ad 3 products then total price will shown 3 times and if 2 products are in cart then it show 2 times

Comment: sory bro after removing the loop it only shows the lastone product prics

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment other answers yet but here is what Mozammil meant:

In your foreach loop you display the Total every time you go through the loop.

```
@foreach($userCart as $cart)
    <span class="m-text22 w-size19 w-full-sm">
    Total:
    </span>

    <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
    PKR: {{ $cart->price*$cart->quantity }}
    </span>
@endforeach
```

Do ONLY the calculation in the loop and then display the total outside of the loop. Check Mozammil's answer for the correct code.